# Interfacing between a PC and custom made circuit

Tags: interface

I'm working on a project where I want to install a photodetector circuit to a computer through some sort of interface (preferably USB). However, since I am new at this so I do not know in what direction that I should approach this problem on. Assuming I have a photodector circuit with a USB connection, does the "interfacing" require only writing the device driver? Or do I need to do any additional work? Please advise if I am overlooking something. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to communicate with your computer would be using an integrated circuit that does all the communication for you. Take a look e.g. at the [FTDI FT232 Chip](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm). It is extremly simple to use as it emulates a virtual COM port in the basic mode (USB drivers for all major platforms are included). So the only thing you would have to do on the PC side would be writing to the serial (COM) port.

Then your microcontroller circuit can simply communicate with this chip via UART, which is supported by almost every controller (e.g. Atmel ATmega series).

Alternatively you can simply use your real RS232-Port, but many modern computer don't have such a port anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't quite understand where the FTDI FT232 Chip fits in. Assuming I have a breadboard circuit implementation, how would I use the FTDI FT232 Chip? Thanks again

Comment: Well, I guess your circuit includes a microcontroller somewhere. The FT232 is then placed between your computer and the microcontroller. So it's basically `PC <--USB--> FT232 <--UART--> Microcontroller`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one possible is obviously through the LPT port.

Out of its 25 pins, 8 are available for input/output and can be connected to any sort of electronic device... including your custom PCB.
It takes simple values :

0 - 00000000

1 - 00000001

2 - 00000010

3 - 00000011

.

.

.

.

255 - 11111111

Check this out for pinouts http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTQy9wmJzTBVAJjMwEdavBoypcwFOXwQ-sA5E2aR-dBLyn1_DDRfg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the computer that I am using does not have a parallel port :(. Thanks though!